# Where can I find the tsconfig.json defaults?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I can easily find the compiler option defaults for TypeScript by going to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html **but I cannot find the tsconfig.json defaults**.

Where can I find the tsconfig.json defaults?

In particular I'm looking for the default for compileOnSave.

Comment: Nope it doesn't, I have tested `compileOnSave` and the default is false, but I'd like to know for certain that this is the case. The documentation you linked to only shows how to set `compileOnSave` to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this we can use JSON schema for [tsconfig](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig). There we can see that there is no default value associated with `compileOnSave` property.

So I guess the answer is - there is no default value for it. tsc treats absence of the property as if "compile on save" is disabled.

Note. The default property in the JSON schema is just a hint and has no real connection to the actual data, so its up to tsc developers to follow the schema defaults properly, and I really hope they do.

Comment: Is it just me or would it not make sense to have a default value for everything so that the schema is followed in a consistent fashion?

Comment: I would make total sense.